# How to click on handle Chrome's "save as" dialog using Java in LeanFT Tool?

Tags: java, automation, leanft

Using LeanFT's Java SDK, is it possible to perform click operation on "Save" button from [Chrome's "Save As" dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4hNBV.png)?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
String home = System.getenv("USERPROFILE") + "\\Downloads\\";
String fileName = "xxxxxxxxx.xls";
File file = new File(home + fileName);
if (file.exists()) {
   file.delete();
   System.out.println("Deleted existing CurrentSortRules.xls file if it is already present");
    }
    Window popup = Desktop.describe(Window.class, new WindowDescription.Builder().ownedWindow(false).childWindow(false)
                                .windowClassRegExp("Chrome_WidgetWin_1").windowTitleRegExp(" Google Chrome").build())
                .describe(Dialog.class, new DialogDescription.Builder().ownedWindow(true).childWindow(false)
                        .text("Save As").nativeClass("#32770").build());
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the [Object Identification Tool](https://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/TestObjects_OIC.htm) to identify the **Save** button?

In any case, I understand you are now working with **Web** technology, then you click on a Save button, which then prompts you to save the file in a location.

You have two options:

1. Set Chrome to no longer ask where to save files;
2. Describe the Save button that you want to Click using the **STD** technology.

Example of such description:

```
Desktop.describe(Window.class, new WindowDescription.Builder()
        .ownedWindow(false)
        .childWindow(false)
        .windowClassRegExp("Chrome_WidgetWin_1")
        .windowTitleRegExp(" Google Chrome").build())
    .describe(Dialog.class, new DialogDescription.Builder()
        .ownedWindow(true)
        .childWindow(false)
        .text("Save As")
        .nativeClass("#32770").build())
    .describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
        .text("&Save")
        .nativeClass("Button").build());
```

Then you can call the `.click` method on this object (or cancel, or so on).